# how to fire a function after the post is created or edited

Tags: wordpress, hook

I require to insert the recently edited or inserted into another website. I tried the wp_insert_post action hook. But it execute more times 4 or 5 times. Please suggest me the idea.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

publish_post doesn't work for custom post types, the correct hook (action hook) is publish_{$custom_post_type}. You should use add_action() as this is an action hook.
Or use wp_insert_post()

Answer (score 1):

[publish_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post)

Use "publish_post" hook which use to trigger after edit / add post in wordpress.